# How can I also cover the battery bar in the Vant 4 popup component in a Vue 3 project?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

How can I also cover the battery bar in the Vant 4 popup component in a Vue 3 project?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CENWt.jpg)

I don't know how to implement it, and I'm unsure how to access the battery bar. I don't see the battery bar in the browser developer tools